# Comparison Test in $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, riemann-integration

**Comparison Test in $\Bbb R^n$:**

Let $A$ be open in $\Bbb R^n$; let $f,g : A \to \Bbb R$ be continuous; suppose that $|f(x)| < g(x)$ for $x \in A$. Show that if $\int_A g$ exists, so does $\int_A f$.

Can someone provide me some reference from where I can get the proof?

Also Hints for proving the statement are welcome.

Thank You.

Comment: What definition of integral are you using? Riemann? Lebesgue?

Comment: riemann integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is continuous, the integral $\int_X f$ is defined for all $X$ compact. So the only issue is boundedness of the (possibly improper) integral at $A$.

Since $A$ is open, we may write $A=\bigcup A_n$, an increasing union of compact sets. Then we would define 
$$
\int_A f=\lim_n \int_{A_n}f,
$$
if the limit exists. The fact that $\int_A g$ exists, tells us that $$\int_A g=\lim_n\int_{A_n}g.$$ Thus $$ \lim_n \int_{A\setminus A_n} g=0.$$ Then, if $A_n\subset A_m$, 
$$
\left|\int_{A_m}f-\int_{A_n}f\right|=\left|\int_{A_m\setminus A_n}f\right|\leq\int_{A_m\setminus A_n}|f|
\leq\int_{A\setminus A_n}|f|\leq  \int_{A\setminus A_n}g\to0.
$$
So the sequence $\{\int_{A_n}f\}$ is Cauchy, and so $\int_A f$ exists.